# Use of duplicate slugs, without -1

Tags: slug

Is there a way/workaround for using "duplicate" slugs?

**Example:**

- shop.com/candy (category page with listing of candy's)
- shop.com/about-us/candy (plain page with info about the production process etc)

Normally Craft will automatically generate for the second slug "candy-1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft doesn't care what the individual slug of an entry is on its own, it looks at the whole path to see if there are duplicates.

Therefore having `shop.com/candy` and `shop.com/about-us/candy` shouldn't be a problem, provided the `Entry URI Format` has been setup correctly for your Sections.

It should take into account the slug of parent entries in generating their own. I use this:

`{parent.uri ?? ''}/{slug}`

Comment: Thanks Jamie for your reply!

`{parent.uri ?? ''}/{slug}` did the trick